# image's corner in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working in this app and I have a problem first the pic doesn't take the all size of the clipRRect, then I used the Ink.Image and the BoxFit.fitHeight, it okay but now the pic doesnt take the radius of the clipRRect..
sorry for my weak english, here is the code and screenshoot for the app.
please check the pics its in link.
thanks alot.

```
Widget foodCard() {
return Padding(
  padding:  EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
   child: Container(
    child: FittedBox(
      child: Material(
          color: Colors.white,
          elevation:8.0 ,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0),
          ),
        child: Row(children: [
          Container(
            width: 250, height: 250,
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0)),
                child: Ink.image(
                  height: 200,
                  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  image: NetworkImage(
                  "https://images-gmi-pmc.edge-generalmills.com/087d17eb-500e-4b26-abd1-4f9ffa96a2c6.jpg"
                )),)
          ),
          Container(
            child: Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(children: [
              Text("Recipe 1",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),
              Text("Some data"),
              ButtonBar(children: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text('Like'),
                    color: Colors.deepPurple,
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text('Dislike'),
                    color: Colors.deepPurple,
                    onPressed: () {},
                  ),
                ],)
            ]),)
          )
        ],)
    )
  ),
));
```

}
[before using fitbox.fithieght](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6r7e.png)

[after using it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcSR1.png)

[I want the picture to be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pahnJ.png)

Comment: Can you post a pic on how you want the image to look?

Comment: if you want the image to fill the left row completely, try `fit: BoxFit.fill`

Comment: I want it this way, but I want the Radius to apply on it.

Comment: I mean the Radius applid to the container I want to apply it on the picture too.

Comment: i tried using boxfit.fill and its hide the left top radius circular

Comment: Could you swap between ```ClipRRect``` and ```Container``` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Sample]

copy and paste this Widget.

```
Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Material(
            color: Colors.white,
            elevation: 8.0,
            shadowColor: Colors.blueGrey,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
            child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                child: FittedBox(
                    child: Material(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        elevation: 8.0,
                        shadowColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                                width: 250,
                                height: 250,
                                child: Ink.image(
                                    height: 200,
                                    fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                    image: NetworkImage(
                                        "https://images-gmi-pmc.edge-generalmills.com/087d17eb-500e-4b26-abd1-4f9ffa96a2c6.jpg"))),
                            Container(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Column(children: [
                                Text(
                                  "Recipe 1",
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                ),
                                Text("Some data"),
                                ButtonBar(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    FlatButton(
                                      child: Text('Like'),
                                      color: Colors.deepPurple,
                                      onPressed: () {},
                                    ),
                                    FlatButton(
                                      child: Text('Dislike'),
                                      color: Colors.deepPurple,
                                      onPressed: () {},
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                )
                              ]),
                            ))
                          ],
                        )))),
          ),
        )
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it is worked just like I want it! 
could you please tell me what the thing I have made wrong in my code so it doesn't give me the same result?